# How browserify shimming works? CommonJs and Non-CommonJs modules

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, jquery-plugins, browserify

*Premise 1*: If some piece of javascript is available via npm then that piece is written in CommonJs style, so there is not need for shimming it? (here im focused on the client side modules, like jquery, backbone, jquery plugins etc)

*Premise 2*: Browserify will never create global variable by it's own?

**Simple example:**

**index.html**

```
<p>Click me</p>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**entry_point.js**

```
var test = require('./test');
```

**test.js**

```
var $      = require('jquery');
var test1 = require('./test1'); 

$('body').css({ 'background': '#c0c0c0' });
```

**test1.js**

```
var $ = require('jquery');

$('p').click(function() { alert("you clicked on paragraph"); });
```

So running `browserify entry_point.js -o bundle.js` everything is working nicely and nothing is attacthed to global(window) object. *Every module that needs to do something through jquery needs to include jquery first,* **because jquery is not global**. To compare this with standard way of including jquery:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image]

Now lets say that i need to include some jquery-plugin which is not written in CommonJs style, for example https://github.com/drewwilson/TipTip.

*Premise 3*. In order to use some library with browserify which is not written in CommonJs style i must to shimm that library?

After a lot of trial and errors, and reading similar question on stackoverflow, somehow i manage it to work. I installed `browserify-shim` via. `npm install --save-dev browserify-shim` and i added some boilerplate to `package.json` in order to work.

**Simple example refactored to use shimming:**

```
{
    "browserify": {
        "transform": [
            "browserify-shim"
        ]
    },
    "browser": {
        "jquery": "./jquery.min.js",
        "jquery-tipTip": "./jquery.tipTip.js"
    },
    "browserify-shim": {
        "jquery": {
            "exports": "$"
        },
        "jquery-tipTip": {
            "depends": [
                "jquery"
            ],
            "exports": "null"
        }
   }
}
```

**index.html**

```
<p>Click me</p>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

**entry_point.js**

```
var $      = require('jquery');
var tipTip = require('jquery-tipTip');
var test   = require('./test');
```

**test.js**

```
$('body').css({ 'background': '#c0c0c0' });
```

**test1.js**

```
$('p').click(function() { alert("you clicked on paragraph"); });
$('p').tipTip({ content: "bla bla" });
```

*So after shimming* (because of only one plugin) browserify made everything global, i dont need to require jquery from each module now i can require it only in entry_point.js, which i dont like.

[image]

In this way i have felling that i don't use too much of browserify.

Is this good way of shimming stuff which are not written in CommonJS style? Is there some way to write second example without attaching anything to global(which browserify does by default)

**If it is possible i would like to keep same logic after shimming, so if any module needs jquery or jquery-plugin that module needs to require both of them.**

Comment: Sorry, but you have a lot of "garbage" in your question which makes it really hard to understand what you want. From what I read I can advise you to use browserify only for CommonJS modules and use plain scripts as they are in browser, you are trying to complicate things which don't need to.

Comment: @micnic: I don't think this is a bad question. It could do with a TL;DR at the top, but it's clear he put a lot of effort into explaining his problem. The question is bolded at the bottom. I don't  know why I'm replying to this, as it's 1.5 years old...